# Converting DateTime.Now from "ar-EG" to "en-US" to avoid ص/م time abbreviation

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert DateTime.Now object from culture("ar-EG") to culture("en-us") to get rid of [ص/م] time abbreviations so I used this piece of code `string cnow = DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));` it works fine., but when trying to convert it back to DateTime object using this code `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(cnow)` I get this exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I can not figure it out why this happen. and how to get this conversion done in this case?

-- Update --

I have to do this conversion as I'm trying to get TimeSpan between two different dates with two distinct culture as mentioned above.

-- Update 2 --

The necessity of this conversion is because my application will run on many different cultures and results errors when inserting these dates into database.

Comment: A `DateTime` stores the number of 100ns intervals that have occurred since midnight at the start of 01/01/0001. It doesn't contain *any* strings. `DateTime.Now` called from two different threads using two different cultures at exactly the same time will return two *identical* values.

Comment: Re: your update, no, they don't remember culture at all. As I said, it's [the number of ticks since 01/01/0001](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,130) and that's it. That's it's *only* instance field, a single `UInt64` with a couple of the upper bits for implementing the `Kind` property. Whatever your problem is, if you're working with two `DateTime` objects, it's *not* a formatting or culture issue

Comment: You created a string with `en-US` culture but you _expect_ to parse it with `ar-EG` (at least I assume it was your `CurrentCulture`). Do you see what is _wrong_ here?

Comment: If you don't use _any_ culture as a parameter with `DateTime.Parse` method, it will use your `CurrentCulture` settings. And in your case, it seems different than `en-US`.

Comment: Re: update 2 - again, you're getting errors because you're performing conversions to *strings*. If you keep everything in `DateTime` variables throughout and pass the data to your database as *parameters* rather than (presumably) forcing a string conversion and building up queries via string concatenation then a) you *won't* have any culture/formatting issues and b) you'll avoid SQL Injection. Any formatting/culture issues are arising because, somewhere or other, you're taking well formed data and converting to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the clue, just I will force my entire application to work on a specific culture instead of relying on Windows current culture using this line of code at very start of application code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `DateTime.Parse` overload that also takes an `IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) (`CultureInfo` implements `IFormatProvider`). Otherwise, the current culture will be used for parsing.

Comment: Converting to/from strings is pointless dancing - if it's successfully converted back to a `DateTime` and it's not lost any information, the exact same value that was started with will be the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this i hope help you to solve problem : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This is a only-link answer. Wouldn't be better as a comment instead?